# How to delete cell contains zero and the cells after it

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need to delete all numbers (cell contents) after the cell that contains zero in the same row!  how may I do it?

[image]

Comment: You can use Excel's "Find and Replace" (Ctrl + F) functionality. Find "0" and replace all the occurrences by "" (blank). You should "Match entire cell contents" in the ">> Options".

Comment: i need to delete also the cells after zero not zero only !

Comment: what is meant by after? row or column?

Comment: row not column.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to create a new table, or use VBA, as a formula will overwrite the present value of the table.

You can use a formula such as:

```
=IF(OR(A1=0,E1=0),0,A1)
```

You first need to create a column of `x`'s after the table. The formula then reads the corresponding cell from the original table, and if this is zero, **OR** the previous cell in the new table is zero (this is where the `x`'s as used - to allow the new table to get started), then place a zero in the new table, or place the existing value.

[image: remove_zeroes]

Comment: i tried it but didn't get the right result